# Wrong suggested edit markdown comparison; no visual line-to-line matching

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, markdown

I just made [this suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/316957). The comparison is wrong and incorrectly shows that I deleted a bunch of text, then added another bunch of text. This could give reviewers a wrong impression.

What I really did was just format the original bunch of text (not delete and replace it with something else). I'm looking for an improvement in the compare algorithms used, so as to show what actually happened.

The comparison page layout also doesn't match lines with lines. The text that comes after the problem text is in different vertical positions, making it more difficult to compare what changed.

**Note:** While my own suggested edit may be approved, I cite it here as an example to show the problems with the compare algorithm, to help improve all comparisons in general and help reviewers make a better decision.

[image: Screenshot showing wrong comparison and lack of line matching]

Comment: Please help move this to [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) if it better fits there. Thanks!

Comment: Switching the view to "rendered output" instead of "markdown" shows more clearly the effect of the edit in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example was one the cases I used test my [diff engine improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258959/115866), and as you can [see](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/316957), it looks much better now:

[image: screenshot of the fixed diff]

Comment: ***Thank you!***